# Power shell User Loop for Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I got this to work for calling single users in the AD and updating their properties. I have to rename the CN= to a different user every time. In order to update properties for all users in an OU do i use the distinguishedName of the User's folder? Or do i need to loop through the user's CN in the folder? I am a bit stummped.

````
get-aduser -SearchBase "CN=Bill,OU=Users,OU=***,DC=***,DC=***" -Filter * | set-aduser -streetAddress "***" -City "***" -State "***"-PostalCode "*****" -Country "**" -Office "***" -Company "***"```
````

Comment: You can put an OU DN in the `-SearchBase` then use the `-Filter` to find users that meet a filtering condition but your question is vague. Its not clear what exactly you're looking for

Comment: Or am did i over complicate it and it only requires the DC parameters in the SearchBase?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon hello, thanks for ur comment, as of now the AD has no information filled in the Address fields etc. I am trying to create a script that will update and fill all users address info. I guess what I am asking is how do i reference all users in the AD to all be updated at once?

Comment: Assuming each user will have his/her own address information, where is that stored? Do you have a CSV file or something to get that data from?

Comment: I was able to figure it out! @Theo ```get-aduser -SearchBase "DC=,DC=" -Filter * | set-aduser -streetAddress "" -City "" -State ""-PostalCode "" -Country "US" -Office "" -Company ""```

Comment: I don't get it.. With that code you are trying to set all those attributes for each of the users to an empty string?? As commented, where do you get the address info for the users from. A Csv file or what?